# Is it possible to calibrate Mertons Jump Diffusion Model such that it matches mean and vola from a normal process without jumps?

Tags: volatility, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, jump-diffusion, skewness

I'm currently playing around with Mertons version of jump diffusion processes where i'm testing the predicitions of a trading model given a time series with and without jumps to isolate the effects of an increase in skewness of the time series on the outcomes of that model. Until now, the predicitions are in line with what i expected, however, my results are somewhat diluted by the fact that i can match the mean of the original simulated time series (GBM without jumps) but not its vola. So the results of this model are driven by a change in skewness and in vola, which is bad as i want to isolate the effect of an increase in skewness alone.

I tried to substract a "discount" from the observed datapoints of the jump-process and add jumpsize for a given jump probability to get my desired skewness hoping to find a way such that both moments match. I know that if i add more discount, my vola will increase but my mean will shrink, so this is certainly not the correct way of obtaining what i'm looking for. Please note that i'm using historical stock prices as time series and have no interest in option pricing.

What is a better way of archiving what i am looking for? Please let me know in the comments if my question is not entirely clear, i will post code and some of my data here then.
As always i appreciate any hints
Yours Thomas

Comment: First of all: Merton's model leads to nonnegative prices and you want to to match a normal model with it. Second: if that was a typo and you want to match a GBM without jumps with Merton's model I see a very easy way to do so: set the jump size to zero and use the same vol as in GBM. Rather than posting code and sharing data you may use some formulas to explain what you are actually doing.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your comments, yes, its a typo, I'll correct it. The second remark is a quite obvious one, which doesn't help as i want to have a positive jump size. I'll check in what way i can make this question clearer

Comment: I think I do not understand what you are looking for. I understand that you want to match two moments of your observed return sample (mean, variance) using Merton's jump diffusion paramaterisation. The model has four degrees of freedom (diffusion volatility, jump intensity, jump mean and variance). The corresponding moment matching equation system thence yields a remaining degree of freedom. You should be able to calibrate a model in (some | most) cases, no?

Comment: I see its not clear what i want, thus i have to rephrase my question